# Mongoose get the subdocument that was just saved

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
 router.route('/')
    .post((req, res) => {
      Circle.findOne({title: req.params.circle_title}, (err, circle) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err)
        }

        circle.posts.push({
          authorId: req.body.authorId,
          body: req.body.body
        })

        circle.save((err, savedCircle) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
          }

          res.json(savedCircle.posts[savedCircle.posts.length-1]) // FIXME
        })
      })
    })
```

In the above code, I would like to know if there's a better way to return the `post` that was just saved, which is a subdocument of a `circle`.

Comment: Why not return the `_id` of the new post and query the `Post` collection?

Comment: If the answer is not up to the mark/not working for you could you update the reason in comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

Immediately after your save, you need to findOne and populate:

```
circle.save((err, savedCircle) {

      if (err) {
        return res.send(err)
      }

      Circle.findOne(savedCircle).populate('post.Ref_Id').exec(function(err,    results) {
           console.log(results);
      });

      res.json(results);

    })
 }
```

---

Even you could do directly on the resultant/saved document.

```
savedCircle.populate('post.Ref_Id').exec(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

---

The best way is to have a reference to the recently pushed object. e.g:

```
    circle.posts.push({
      authorId: req.body.authorId,
      body: req.body.body
    });
    latestSavedcirclePost = circle.posts[0]; //Here you will get _id ref as well
```

---

You can try to use create method instead of pushing/adding them to the array, e.g:

```
 var latestSavedcirclePost = circle.post.create({
      authorId: req.body.authorId,
      body: req.body.body
 });
```